# A service for decoding LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have inherited some LINQ and I want to rewrite it as non-LINQ C# so I can work out which bit is failing.

(I have ordered ReSharper but JetBrains seem slow with licence keys.)

The LINQ is

```
var accounts = from a in srvContext.CreateQuery<Incident>()
                join b in srvContext.CreateQuery<integ_benefitallowances>() on a.integ_BenefitId.Id equals b.integ_benefitallowancesId.Value
                where b.integ_BenefitId.Id == _currentIncident.integ_BenefitId.Id
                where a.Integ_DependantId.Id == a.Integ_DependantId.Id
                where a.integ_ClaimStatus.Value == 0 || a.integ_ClaimStatus.Value == 2
                where a.Integ_DateofClaim.Value > timePeriod
                select new Incident
                {
                     LogicalName = a.LogicalName
                };
```

The error is

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: There was an error with this process
variable '<>h__TransparentIdentifier2' of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`2[PaycareCRM.Incident,PaycareCRM.integ_benefitallowances]' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined
```

Is there a website or simple tool that will convert the LINQ to normal C# for me?

Comment: FWIW, you can download a trial version of ReSharper that will work for 30 days before it requires a license key to continue functioning.

Comment: Some other things you might try are to trace the actual query being executed, and perhaps use LINQPad to assist in translating the LINQ code.

Comment: Define "normal C#". Indeed, this is very simple query...

Comment: "normal C#"?? - What are you talking about? LINQ is part of "normal C#". C# is not (crappy dinosaur) java.

Comment: @HighCore You know what I mean

Comment: "How to refer to C# code that is not LINQ" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19136876/how-to-refer-to-c-sharp-code-that-is-not-linq

Comment: Regarding your trial of Resharper expiring, I'm sure if you sent them an email, they would extend the trial period.

Comment: I did that three times at a previous job. It's so good I decided it wasn't fair to do it again.

Comment: @cja like...maybe enough to pay for it?

Comment: Yes. See my question. They just haven't sent me the licence key yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was revealed by ReSharper - one line was a tautology (and the RS underlining highlighted it), although I don't see why this means the query was failing. Anyway, the fixed code is

```
var incidents = from a in srvContext.CreateQuery<Incident>()
                join b in srvContext.CreateQuery<integ_benefitallowances>() on a.integ_BenefitId.Id equals b.integ_benefitallowancesId.Value
                where b.integ_BenefitId.Id == _currentIncident.integ_BenefitId.Id
                where a.Integ_DependantId.Id == _currentIncident.Integ_DependantId.Id
                where a.integ_ClaimStatus.Value == 0 || a.integ_ClaimStatus.Value == 2
                where a.Integ_DateofClaim.Value > timePeriod
                select new Incident
                        {
                                LogicalName = a.LogicalName
                        };
```

Answer (score 4):

XY problem.

[DataServiceContext does not support Join or Select (except as the identity operator).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622463.aspx#unsupportedMethods)

Comment: Yes and no. The C# compiles. The Query does not. The `IQueryable` interface is just that. An interface. When executing the query, the `IQueryProvider` takes the Expression Tree and then "compiles" to Expression Tree to some query...in this case an OData Query String. If all that sounded complex, that is because it is...